# count(*)> expression in xpath building

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

While reading an online blog i came across the below xpath,

```
xpath=//body/div[3]/form/fieldset/select[count(*)>1]
```

and the UI HTML looks like 
[image: Select UI]

What will be the xpath output? Is the Author tries to check whether the Select options are more than one ? (boolean answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query will return all `<select/>` elements with more than one option to choose from. If so, the predicate is true and the `<select/>` element gets included, otherwise not.

Actually this is not *quite* correct, as it would fail to recognize `<option/>`s in `<optgroup/>`s:

```
<select>
  <optgroup>
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>bar</option>
    <option>batz</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Which definitely has more than one option, but still only one direct child node. A better solution probably would be to use (I cut off the path in the beginning).

```
//select[count(.//*)>1]
```

Comment: Fine, So ' 

driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//body/div[3]/form/fieldset/select[count(.//*)>1] ")).size(); '

is the Number of 'SELECT' which has more than one option. Am i Right ?

Comment: Yep. <!-- 11 more to go -->